# Concat function in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, hive, coalesce

I have the below select statement in hive .It executes perfectely fine.

In Hive

```
select
COALESCE(product_name,CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(TRIM(product_id),' - 
'),trim(plan_code)),' - UNKNOWN')) as product_name
from table name;
```

I am trying to use the same select statement in POSTGRESQL and it throw me error saying "

Query execution failed

Reason:

> SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function concat(text, unknown) does not exist
>   Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

In postgresql:

```
select
COALESCE(product_name,CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(TRIM(product_id),' - 
'),trim(plan_code)),' - UNKNOWN')) as product_name
from table name;
```

Could some one throw some light on this ?

Comment: This should work for text columns. What are the types of the columns?

Comment: `concat_ws()` could simplify this string expression. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html

Comment: @klin: Data types are text

Comment: `concat()` was introduced in Postgres 9.1, probably you  use an older version. Upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of concat try with `||`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(product_name, 
        (TRIM(product_id) || ' - ' || TRIM(plan_code) || ' - UNKNOWN')
       ) AS product_name 
FROM tablename;
```

or simply a single CONCAT as:

```
SELECT COALESCE(product_name, 
         CONCAT(TRIM(product_id)::text, ' - ', TRIM(plan_code)::text, ' - UNKNOWN') 
       ) AS product_name
FROM tablename;
```

Comment: column data types are text . Even i tried above query defining data types explicitly .But it gives me the same error.

Comment: @user8545255 `SELECT COALESCE(product_name, 
         (TRIM(product_id) || ' - ' || TRIM(plan_code) || ' - UNKNOWN')
       ) AS product_name
FROM tablename;` is this working

Comment: Just be aware that || will return null if any of the strings to be concatenated are null.  The concat function does not do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider using [format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-string.html) function:

```
SELECT coalesce(product_name, format('%s - %s - UNKNOWN', trim(product_id), trim(plan_code)))
```